# Pandas timedeltas ignoring date

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, timedelta

I have 2 pandas series, each containing a times as strings:

```
times = pd.DataFrame({'bedtime': ['23:00', '0:30', '1:00'], 'waketime': ['6:00', '6:00', '4:00']})
print(times)

  bedtime waketime
0   23:00     6:00
1    0:30     6:00
2    1:00     4:00
```

I want to calculate the difference between the times (essentially the amount of time spent sleeping), however, I don't have date information so its a bit problematic

I start by converting each series to datetime:

```
FMT = "%H:%M"
bedtime = pd.to_datetime(times["bedtime"], format=FMT)
waketime = pd.to_datetime(times["waketime"], format=FMT)
```

This process adds a date to the times, which I dont want:

```
print(bedtime)
1900-01-01 23:00:00
1900-01-01 00:30:00
1900-01-01 01:00:00
```

Because a date has been added, the time delta is occasionally shifted by a day:

```
hours_in_bed = waketime - bedtime
print(hours_in_bed)

-1 days +07:00:00
         05:30:00
         03:00:00
```

Whats the correct way to calculate a time delta when the actual date is not desired? I basically just want to calculate elapsed duration in **hours** between going to bed and waking up

I've seen other questions about how to remove the date from the datetime object, but here I'm more concerned about correcting/removing the 1 day shift in the time delta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) for convert `times`, but problem is still same:

```
FMT = "%H:%M"
bedtime = pd.to_timedelta(times["bedtime"] + ':00', 'h')
waketime = pd.to_timedelta(times["waketime"] + ':00', 'h')
print(bedtime)
0   23:00:00
1   00:30:00
2   01:00:00
Name: bedtime, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

print(waketime)
0   06:00:00
1   06:00:00
2   04:00:00
Name: waketime, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

hours_in_bed = waketime - bedtime
print(hours_in_bed)
0   -1 days +07:00:00
1            05:30:00
2            03:00:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Solution is only parse [`seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.seconds.html) and use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) with parameter `s`:

```
hours_in_bed = pd.to_timedelta(hours_in_bed.dt.seconds, unit='s')
print(hours_in_bed)
0   07:00:00
1   05:30:00
2   03:00:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

If need output in `hours`, divide `3600.0`:

```
hours_in_bed = hours_in_bed.dt.seconds / 3600.0
print(hours_in_bed)
0    7.0
1    5.5
2    3.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your delta includes a negative day simply reflects the fact that one got to sleep later (at 23:00:00) than woke up (at 6:00). You either need to add date to your original data frame, or live with this. You can easily eliminate the day part:

```
hours_in_bed.apply(lambda x : (x.components.hours,x.components.minutes))
#0     (7, 0)
#1    (5, 30)
#2     (3, 0)
#dtype: object
```